# Swift API Design Guide - Initializer and factory methods calls

Tags: swift, design-guidelines

[Swift API Design Guide](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines) says:

> The first argument to initializer and factory methods calls should not form a phrase starting with the base name

Specially, it advises us against writing things like:

```
let foreground = Color(havingRGBValuesRed: 32, green: 64, andBlue: 128)
let newPart = factory.makeWidget(havingGearCount: 42, andSpindleCount: 14)
let ref = Link(to: destination)
```

But in the Swift Standard Library or UIKit we find code like:

```
struc Array<T> {
    // ...

    init(repeating repeatedValue: Array.Element, count: Int)
}    

class UIImage {
   // ...

   init?(
        named name: String, 
        in bundle: Bundle?, 
        compatibleWith traitCollection: UITraitCollection?
    )
}
```

Is it correct?